# What causes the failure of the join method when used in this Angular app's template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15

I have been working an app with Angular 15.

I use a hand-coded JSON and [JSON server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) to display a list of "employees".

```
{"employees": [
    {
      "empno": "2",
      "deptno": "10",
      "firstname": "Sandy",
      "lastname": "Paton",
      "gender": "femele",
      "avatar": "sandy.png",
      "job": "Manager",
      "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam obcaecati veritatis maiore.",
      "skills": "['Management']"
    },
    {
      "empno": "8",
      "deptno": "30",
      "firstname": "Susette",
      "lastname": "Lumbard",
      "gender": "femele",
      "avatar": "femele.png",
      "job": "Programmer",
      "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam obcaecati veritatis maiore.",
      "skills": "['JAVA', 'MySQL']"
    },
    {
      "empno": "10",
      "deptno": "10",
      "firstname": "Sue",
      "lastname": "Jary",
      "gender": "femele",
      "avatar": "femele.png",
      "job": "HR Manager",
      "bio": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam obcaecati veritatis maiore.",
      "skills": "['Recruitment']"
    }
]}
```

In `employee-details.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/services/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-details',
  templateUrl: './employee-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-details.component.scss'],
})
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  public empsArray: Employee[] = [];
  public employee: any = {};

  public getEmployee() {
    const empno = Number(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('empno'));

    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe((response) => {
      this.empsArray = response;

      this.employee = this.empsArray.find((item) => item.empno == empno);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployee();
  }
}
```

In `employee-details.component.html` I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start mb-3 mt-1">
        <img
          src="assets/images/{{ employee.avatar }}"
          [alt]="employee.firstname"
          class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
      <h2>{{ employee.firstname }} {{ employee.lastname }}</h2>
  
      <p>{{ employee.bio }}</p>
  
      <div *ngIf="employee.skills.length">
        <h3>Skills</h3>
        <p>
          {{ employee.gender == 'male' ? 'His' : 'Her' }} main skills are:
          {{ employee.skills.join(', ') }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The problem

Whenever I access the details of an employee, I get this error in the Chrome console:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

This happend even though `{{ employee.skills }}` *does* print the array of skills.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: Try adding an optional chaining to your skills.length like this `employee.skills?.length`, if it still produces the same error, then the error might be from somewhere else.

Comment: @JkAlombro It produces the same result.

Comment: It might be from somewhere else. Does the error in console at least give you the stack trace on which function the error is coming from? other option would be to search `.length` within that module/feature's folder to trace other arrays that uses length because that's the only clue that we have atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the quotes in your .json, else skills are not an array, see the diference

```
"employees": [
    {
      ...
      "skills": "['Management']" //<--is a string
    },
}
```

And

```
"employees": [
    {
      ...
      "skills": ['Management']  //<--is an array of strings
    },
]
```

If really you get string, you should transform (you can use regexpr)

In your service

```
getData()
{
    return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
       map((employees:any[])=>{
         employees.forEach(x=>{
           x.skills=x.skills.match(/\'([^,])*\'/g)?
                     .map(x=>x.slice(0,-1).slice(1))
         })
         return employees
       })
    )
}

getEmploye(employedId)
{
      this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
         map((employee:any)=>{
             employee.skills=employee.skills.match(/\'([^,])*\'/g)?
                         .map(x=>x.slice(0,-1).slice(1))
             return employee
         })
      )
}
```

**Update** I don't know because I have problem with the code above in strict mode, I replace the forEach by a map and the functions becomes like

```
  getData() {
    const obs = of(employesData);
    return obs.pipe(
      map((employees: any[]) => {
        const regex = /\'([^,])*\'/g;
        return employees.map((employe: any) => {
          const skills = (employe.skills as string)
            .match(regex)
            ?.map((x: string) => x.slice(0, -1).slice(1));
          return { ...employe, skills: skills };
        });
      })
    );
  }
  getDataEmployed(empno: string) {
    const obs = of(employesData.find((x: any) => x.empno == empno));
    const regex = /\'([^,])*\'/g;
    return obs.pipe(
      map((employe: any) => {
        const skills = (employe.skills as string)
          .match(regex)
          ?.map((x: string) => x.slice(0, -1).slice(1));
        return { ...employe, skills: skills };
      })
    );
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eghsbu?file=src%2Fdata.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts)

NOTE: I'm not a good coder in regExpr, sure someone can create a better expresion

Comment: The JSON is valid the way I have it. I checked.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that you receive "skills" as a string, even though it seems to be an array. But the error that you're getting happens when that property doesn't exist, or it is `null`.
It's easily fixed if you change the 'if' statement:

```
<div *ngIf="employee.skills?.length">
```

With that question mark, basically you're telling Typescript that the variable/property is optional, and prechecks if it really exists.

Update:
Because join() is an array function. Doesn't work on strings. First you either need to receive an array, or transform the string that you get into an array to iterate into it. The right way is to ask wherever you're receiving the data, to change it and format it the proper way.

Since I know sometimes it isn't possible, I would add a function (in the ts) to parse the skills.

```
function strToArr(str: string) {
    const validJSONString = string.replace(/'/g, '"');
    return JSON.parse(validJSONString);
}
```

And update the template

```
{{ strToArr(employee.skills).join(', ') }}
```

Comment: That results in `ctx_r0.employee.skills.join is not a function` for `{{ employee.skills.join(', ') }}`.